# How to configure the channel for Access Point 5Ghz in hostapd?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, hostapd

I try to create a WIFI Access Point with hostapd. I have the following Wireless adapter :

```
Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

It supports WIFI 802.11a/b/g/n You will find below the result for the command iw list

```
Wiphy phy0
    max # scan SSIDs: 4
    max scan IEs length: 2257 bytes
    Retry short limit: 7
    Retry long limit: 4
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Device supports RSN-IBSS.
    Device supports AP-side u-APSD.
    Device supports T-DLS.
    Supported Ciphers:
            * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
            * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
            * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
            * CCMP (00-0f-ac:4)
            * 00-0f-ac:10
            * GCMP (00-0f-ac:8)
            * 00-0f-ac:9
            * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
            * 00-0f-ac:13
            * 00-0f-ac:11
            * 00-0f-ac:12
    Available Antennas: TX 0x3 RX 0x3
    Configured Antennas: TX 0x3 RX 0x3
    Supported interface modes:
             * IBSS
             * managed
             * AP
             * AP/VLAN
             * monitor
             * mesh point
             * P2P-client
             * P2P-GO
             * Unknown mode (11)
    Band 1:
            Capabilities: 0x11ef
                    RX LDPC
                    HT20/HT40
                    SM Power Save disabled
                    RX HT20 SGI
                    RX HT40 SGI
                    TX STBC
                    RX STBC 1-stream
                    Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
                    DSSS/CCK HT40
            Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
            Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
            HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
            Bitrates (non-HT):
                    * 1.0 Mbps
                    * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                    * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                    * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                    * 6.0 Mbps
                    * 9.0 Mbps
                    * 12.0 Mbps
                    * 18.0 Mbps
                    * 24.0 Mbps
                    * 36.0 Mbps
                    * 48.0 Mbps
                    * 54.0 Mbps
            Frequencies:
                    * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
                    * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
    Band 2:
            Capabilities: 0x11ef
                    RX LDPC
                    HT20/HT40
                    SM Power Save disabled
                    RX HT20 SGI
                    RX HT40 SGI
                    TX STBC
                    RX STBC 1-stream
                    Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
                    DSSS/CCK HT40
            Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
            Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
            HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
            Bitrates (non-HT):
                    * 6.0 Mbps
                    * 9.0 Mbps
                    * 12.0 Mbps
                    * 18.0 Mbps
                    * 24.0 Mbps
                    * 36.0 Mbps
                    * 48.0 Mbps
                    * 54.0 Mbps
            Frequencies:
                    * 5180 MHz [36] (18.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 5200 MHz [40] (18.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 5220 MHz [44] (18.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 5240 MHz [48] (18.0 dBm) (no IR)
                    * 5260 MHz [52] (18.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 1656 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5280 MHz [56] (18.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 1656 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5300 MHz [60] (18.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 1656 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5320 MHz [64] (18.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 1656 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5500 MHz [100] (18.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 1656 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5520 MHz [104] (18.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 1656 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5540 MHz [108] (18.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 1656 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5560 MHz [112] (18.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 1656 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5580 MHz [116] (18.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 1656 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5600 MHz [120] (18.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 1656 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5620 MHz [124] (18.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 1656 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5640 MHz [128] (18.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 1656 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5660 MHz [132] (18.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 1656 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5680 MHz [136] (18.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 1656 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5700 MHz [140] (18.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                      DFS state: usable (for 1656 sec)
                      DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
                    * 5745 MHz [149] (disabled)
                    * 5765 MHz [153] (disabled)
                    * 5785 MHz [157] (disabled)
                    * 5805 MHz [161] (disabled)
                    * 5825 MHz [165] (disabled)
    Supported commands:
             * new_interface
             * set_interface
             * new_key
             * start_ap
             * new_station
             * new_mpath
             * set_mesh_config
             * set_bss
             * authenticate
             * associate
             * deauthenticate
             * disassociate
             * join_ibss
             * join_mesh
             * remain_on_channel
             * set_tx_bitrate_mask
             * frame
             * frame_wait_cancel
             * set_wiphy_netns
             * set_channel
             * set_wds_peer
             * tdls_mgmt
             * tdls_oper
             * probe_client
             * set_noack_map
             * register_beacons
             * start_p2p_device
             * set_mcast_rate
             * connect
             * disconnect
             * channel_switch
             * Unknown command (104)
             * Unknown command (121)
    Supported TX frame types:
             * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
             * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
             * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
             * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
             * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
             * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
             * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
             * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
    Supported RX frame types:
             * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
             * managed: 0x40 0xd0
             * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
             * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
             * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
             * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
             * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
             * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
    WoWLAN support:
             * wake up on disconnect
             * wake up on magic packet
             * wake up on pattern match, up to 14 patterns of 1-256 bytes,
               maximum packet offset 0 bytes
    software interface modes (can always be added):
             * AP/VLAN
             * monitor
    valid interface combinations:
             * #{ managed } <= 2048, #{ AP, mesh point } <= 8, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
               total <= 2048, #channels <= 1, STA/AP BI must match
    HT Capability overrides:
             * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
             * maximum A-MSDU length
             * supported channel width
             * short GI for 40 MHz
             * max A-MPDU length exponent
             * min MPDU start spacing
    Device supports TX status socket option.
    Device supports HT-IBSS.
    Device supports SAE with AUTHENTICATE command
    Device supports low priority scan.
    Device supports scan flush.
    Device supports AP scan.
    Device supports per-vif TX power setting
    P2P GO supports CT window setting
    Driver supports full state transitions for AP/GO clients
    Driver supports a userspace MPM
    Device supports active monitor (which will ACK incoming frames)
    Driver/device bandwidth changes during BSS lifetime (AP/GO mode)
```

I have written the following hostapd.conf

```
#the interface used by the AP
interface=wlan_local

# "a" simply means 5GHz
hw_mode=a

# the channel to use, 0 means the AP will search for the channel with the least interferences (ACS)
channel=40
ieee80211d=1
country_code=FR
ieee80211n=1

# 802.11ac support
ieee80211ac=1
wmm_enabled=1

ssid=MYSSID
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_passphrase=MYPASSWORD
```

I tried with different channels from 0 to 40, but I still have the following message when I start the service hostapd

```
hostapd[1937]: wlan_local: IEEE 802.11 Configured channel (40) not found from the channel list of current mode (2) IEEE 802.11a
hostapd[1937]: wlan_local: IEEE 802.11 Hardware does not support configured channel
```

Do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: I am not entirely familiar with hostapd but does it support the concept of indicating what region you are in?  Different regions allow different frequencies.  When you are making these configuration changes, you are restarting the service, otherwise your changes are not being accepted.  Your adapter is likely only designed to work in specific regions (frequencies) due to government regulation.

Comment: If you are not in France, I would change "country_code=FR", to a more appropriate country code.  *The 802.11ac Wikipedia article should indicate what regions support what channels.*  Are you intentionally trying to use Channel 40?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#5_GHz_or_5.8_GHz_(802.11a/h/j/n/ac/ax) provides a list of nations/regions and permissible frequencies. Some frequencies just are not available depending on where you are.

Comment: I live in Europe (France). It should be working with channel 40 if my understanding of this page is correct: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#5_GHz_or_5.8_GHz_(802.11a/h/j/n/ac/ax)